# If you marry someone with student debt, does half it become your debt?

Tags: marriage, divorce, debt

So if you divorce, you would own half of their debt?

Comment: What state are you asking about? It can vary quite differently depending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in a [community property state like Washington](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=26.16&full=true), a person is not liable for the premarital debts of a spouse (but is responsible for postmarital debts). During the marriage, jointly-owned property is accessible to creditors, but after divorce, there is no risk to the non-debtor. Though, you would be responsible if you were a co-signer on the loan.

Comment: In many states, only the debtor's interest in jointly owned property would be accessible to creditors. And, in states like MA that have tenancy-by-entirety joint ownership, tenancy-by-entirety property would not be subject to the debt of a single spouse that was not co-signed.